# Replace row with another row in 3D numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to replace a specific row of NaN's in a 3-D array (filled with NaN's) with rows of known integer values from a specific column in a text file (ex: 24 rows of column 8). Is there a method to perform this replacement that I have missed in my search for help?

My most recent trial code (of many) is as follows:

```
import numpy as np

tfile = "C:\...\Lee_Gilmer_MEM_GA_01_02_2015.txt"
data = np.genfromtxt(tfile, dtype=None)

#creation of empty 24 hour global matrix
s_array = np.empty((24,361,720))
s_array[:] = np.NAN

#Get values from column 8
c_data = data[:,7]

#Replace all 24 NaN's slices of row 1 column 1 with corresponding 24 row values from column 8
s_array[:,0:1,0:1] = c_data

print s_array
```

This produces a result of:

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (24) into shape (24,1,1)
```

When I print out the shape of `c_data`, I get:

```
(24L,)
```

Is this at all possible to do without having to use a loop and replacing each one individually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message tells you pretty much everything you need to know: the array slice on the left-hand side of the assignment has a shape of `(24,1,1)`, whereas the right-hand side has shape `(24,)`. Since these shapes don't match, numpy raises a `ValueError`.

There are two ways to solve this:

1. Make the shape of the LHS `(24,)` rather than `(24, 1, 1)`. A nice way to do this would be to index with an integer rather than a slice for the last two dimensions:

   ```
   s_array[:, 0, 0] = c_data
   ```
2. Reshape `c_data` to match the shape of the LHS:

   ```
   s_array[:, 0:1, 0:1] = c_data.reshape(24, 1, 1)
   ```

I think option 1 is a lot more readable.

Comment: Thank you.  Both methods worked, and I now have a better understanding of this aspect of array manipulation.